# How to delay 3 sec. before start send request ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to delay 3 sec. before start send request ajax ?

it's mean user must stay at bottom of page 3 sec, before ajax send requests.

if user stay at bottom of page less than 3 sec, ajax not send requests.

How can i apply this code for do that ?

```
if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())){         
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some_page.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
           $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
           $('#content_data').append(data);
            }
        });
    return false;
```

}

Comment: use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`

Answer (score 1):

To start something in three seconds:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    //...your code here...
}, 3000); // 3000ms = 3 seconds
```

To keep it from happening, before that time is up, do this:

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

In your case, you'd want to:

1. Declare `timer` outside your event handler (I assume your code is in some event handler)
2. Probably set it to `0` to start with (`0` means "no timer", browsers aren't allowed to use `0` as a return value from `setTimeout`)
3. In your handler, before checking the position, Use `clearTimeout` to cancel any previous timer
4. If the condition is true, use the example above to schedule a function to run in three seconds

Then, if the condition becomes true and stays true, the ajax call will run after three seconds. If it becomes true but then false again within the three seconds, it won't run.

Comment: @การกรกรกรกกกนรกี: I think it's best if you learn to do it yourself, which is why the above is written the way it is.